# How we can write a regular expression for ex_date(ddsf#dsd)?

Tags: javascript, regex

When ever #-symbol lies between two string regex pattern should accepts the string. Let say `ex_date( ds23d#d4ff5 )` should accepts the string but, if string is `ex_date( asa#ss32as, #, s3ds#sdsd)`? In this case it should not accept the string.

I tried with this pattern

```
/(([a-z0-9]#[a-z0-9]+(\s|\)|\,|$)))/
```

It should expect `ex_date( d23sd#df32f )`  but not `ex_date(as3a#ss4as, #, sd24s#sd56sd )` because the middle #-symbol is alone means there is no alphanumeric character before # and after #.

*Rules*:

If any where in the string #-symbol is present then string will acceptable only when

- If #-symbol is followed by number like - #12.
- If #-symbol is not present alone like #, (#), [#], ###.
- If #-symbol is followed by only character - ‘dt’ like - #DT or #dt or #dT or #Dt.
- If #-symbol lies between any two alphanumeric character like w3e#ere, 221#we4, er#rr, 12#21.
- If before #-symbol only alphanumeric character is present let say ew1#, ge#, 12#.

Without any #-symbol string are valid unless and until it’s not contain words like (ROW , UROW and COL) like - ROW1, UROW, urow12, row, col1 col323 these are invalid string.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew

If any where in the string #-symbol is present then string will acceptable only when -  
a. If #-symbol is followed by number like - #12.
b. If #-symbol is not present alone  like #, (#), [#],  ###.
c. If  #-symbol is followed by only character -  ‘dt’ like - #DT or #dt or #dT or #Dt.
d. If #-symbol lies between any two alphanumeric character like w3e#ere, 221#we4, er#rr, 12#21.
e. If before #-symbol only alphanumeric character is present let say ew1#, ge#, 12#.

Comment: f. Without any #-symbol string are valid unless and until it’s not contain words like (ROW , UROW and COL) like -   ROW1, UROW, urow12, row, col1 col323 these are invalids string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `ex_date( ds23d#d4ff5 )` is a complete example of what should match, I would phrase the regex as:

```
ex_date\(\s*[a-z0-9]+#[a-z0-9]+\s*\)
```

### Demo

Comment: But it's also accepting  ex_date( ds23d#d4ff5 , we# ) which is not correct.
Here just i taken one example the ex_date function may contains any no of arguments
and also string may be just wew12#wew  without any function too.

Comment: @RahulNigam [My pattern does not match ex_date( ds23d#d4ff5 , we# )](https://regex101.com/r/rhBfJo/2).

Comment: I'm exploring my question so that you can understand in better way - 

I want a pattern that accepts –

1. If any where in the string #-symbol is present then string will acceptable only 
        when - 
 
a. If #-symbol is followed by number like - #12.
b. If #-symbol is not present alone  like #, (#), [#],  ###.
c. If  #-symbol is followed by only character -  ‘dt’ like - #DT or #dt or #dT or 
        #Dt.
d. If #-symbol lies between any two alphanumeric character like w3e#ere, 
        221#we4, er#rr, 12#21.

Comment: e. If before #-symbol only alphanumeric character is present let say ew1#, ge#, 
        12#.
f. Without any #-symbol string are valid unless and until it’s not contain words 
        like (ROW , UROW and COL) like -   ROW1, UROW, urow12, row, col1 
        col323 these are invalids string.

Comment: @Oliver Hao

Can u tell me how we can write a pattern that will accept only if after #-symbol only no will accepts. #-symbol may exists as many time then all the places of # after no will there then only valid other wise invalid.

let say #12, #4545454, p(#34), d( #343, ) all are valid but
p(#12, #er) ,ol(#212er, ) ,  #2332 #445 #we23 all these are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

We can design some expression using two look-arounds:

- What you wish to see in the string (using alternation and a positive lookahead):

  ```
    (?=^.*\b[a-z0-9][a-z]#[a-z][a-z0-9]\b.*$)
  ```
- And what you don't wish to see in the string (using alternation and a negative lookahead):

  ```
    (?!.*[0-9]#[0-9]|.*[a-z]#[0-9]|.*[0-9]#[a-z]|.*[\s,^]#[\s,^])
  ```

Then, we would simply combine those:

```
^(?=^.*[a-z]#[a-z].*$|^.*\b[a-z0-9][a-z]#[a-z][a-z0-9]\b.*$)(?!.*[0-9]#[0-9]|.*[a-z]#[0-9]|.*[0-9]#[a-z]|.*[\s,^]#[\s,^]).*$
```

The only thing is that I'm not sure about the rules, you can modify these rules, however you like.

---

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ENewmn/1)

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ENewmn/1), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ENewmn/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: I tested and tried by  changing regex pattern but I didn't get what exactly I want .


I want if string contains  any no. of #-symbol in the string and before the #symbol and after #symbol if it contains alphanumeric then it's valid string otherwise not.

Comment: In js scripting language

Comment: can u tell me how can I write the pattern that satisfy all the valid cases ?

Comment: regex101.com/r/UdZKmE/1  
in this regex pattern it's accepting all the cases except one 

can u tell what need to modify so that it can accept that case too.

When #-symbol not lie in between two alphanumeric character then in that case after #only the number and character DT is valid not alphanumeric like wew212#wew121 , 12we#121ew are valid but #12we , #we12 , rate(#we12) are not valid because after # it contains both number and character

Comment: Actually it's block me for some days that's why not able to raise new question

Comment: regex101.com/r/UdZKmE/1

Comment: can u check once above regex pattern it's accept all my cases except one which is 

When #-symbol not lie in between two alphanumeric character then in that case after #only the number and character DT is valid not alphanumeric like wew212#wew121 , 12we#121ew are valid but #12we , #we12 , rate(#we12) are not valid because after # it contains both number and character

Comment: will test it and let u know

Comment: can you tell me how we can write a pattern that check accepts a string only if after # no. are there like #12, p( #12 , ) for this.

for the above one I'm writing pattern like -
/(?:(#[0-9]+($|[^a-z0-9])))/.

it's correct for #12, #233 it's accepting but for

p(#12, #12we) this is invalid for this also it's accepting

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead asserting that what is on the right is not a `#` which is surrounded by not a-z or 0-9

```
^(?!.*(?:^|[^a-z0-9])#)(?!.*#(?:$|[^a-z0-9])).+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SjFLlE/1)

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*(?:^|[^a-z0-9])#)(?!.*#(?:$|[^a-z0-9])).+$/;
[
  "ex_date( ds23d#d4ff5 ) ",
  "ex_date( asa#ss32as, #, s3ds#sdsd) ",
  "ex_date12(asa#ss32as,#,s3ds#sdsd) ",
  "( asa#ss32as, a#b, s3ds#sdsd) ",
  "date( asa#ss32as, #, s3ds#sdsd, a#b) ",
  "ex_date( asa#ss32as, a#b, s3ds#sdsd, 4#5) ",
  "ewe#ewe ",
  "we#ere, er2e#er3e, # ",
  "p_price(we#ee) ",
  "p_date( we#rer , ) ",
  "p_car ( df#e ,) ",
  "re#ee , erer#r,",
  "#wewqwq",
  "ddf$%^#gfg^h",

].forEach(s => console.log(regex.test(s) + " ==> " + s));
```

Comment: Yes its working but not accepting all the criteria - 

Lets say in below examples points - 1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12 are only valid except all are invalid , so I want a pattern like this.

1. ex_date( ds23d#d4ff5 )
2. ex_date( asa#ss32as, #, s3ds#sdsd)
3. ex_date12(asa#ss32as,#,s3ds#sdsd)
4. ( asa#ss32as, a#b, s3ds#sdsd)
5. date( asa#ss32as, #, s3ds#sdsd, a#b)
6. ex_date( asa#ss32as, a#b, s3ds#sdsd, 4#5)
7. ewe#ewe
8. we#ere, er2e#er3e, #
9. p_price(we#ee)
10. p_date( we#rer , )
11. p_car ( df#e ,)
12. re#ee , erer#r,

Comment: In the above regex pattern it's also accepting #wewqwq, ddf$%^#gfg^h which is wrong.. . Just I given u example I want a pattern that accepts the above criteria

Comment: Let me tell my question once again I want a pattern that accepts – 
1. If any where in the string #-symbol is present then string will acceptable only when -  

a. If #-symbol is followed by number like - #12
b. If #-symbol is present alone then alone like #, (#), [#]
c. If  #-symbol is followed by only character -  ‘dt’ like - #DT or #dt or #dT or 
        #Dt
d. If #-symbol lies between any two alphanumeric character like w3e#ere, 
        221#we4, er#rr, 12#21.
e. If before #-symbol only alphanumeric character is present let say ew1#, ge#, 
        12#.

Comment: f. Without any #-symbol string are valid unless and until it’s not contain words like (ROW , UROW and COL) like -   ROW1, UROW, urow12, row, col1 col323.

Few examples in which some are valid and some are invalid – 
1. ex_date( ds23d#d4ff5 ) 
2. ex_date( asa#ss32as, #, s3ds#sdsd) 
3. ex_date12(asa#ss32as,#,s3ds#sdsd) 
4. ( asa#ss32as, a#b, s3ds#sdsd) 
5. date( asa#ss32as, #, s3ds#sdsd, a#b) 
6. ex_date( asa#ss32as, a#b, s3ds#sdsd, 4#5, ) 
7. ewe#ewe 
8. we#ere, er2e#er3e, #

Comment: 9. p_price( we#ee ) 
10. p_date( we#rer , ) 
11. p_car ( df#e ,) 
12. re#ee , erer#r,
13. as#
14. 12sd#
15. #as2
16. #DT
17. Ewe
18. ROW1
19. Col
20. Col23
21. Ewecol
22. Ewerow12, 
23. P_price()
Out of these points- 1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 21, 22 and 23 are only valid rest are invalid.

Comment: @RahulNigam Your requirements are expanding. I would suggest adding those requirements to your question.

Comment: ya sure will modify my question

Comment: I'm not able to modify my question can u change the regex pattern that accepts the above criteria.

Comment: I think u cover all most the scenario.. thanks for that @The fourth bird.Except few of them like...

In above example I explained the scenario point-wise. I think u covered the point in the string also.

After #symbol it should accept only number and the word DT not alphanumeric...
like #DT, #12, (#DT , ), (#12) are valid but not #we34, #34ew

Comment: The regex pattern you provided is all-most accepting all scenario but it's also accepting #12sdd, #ew, #sdwe , p_price(#12ty) , p_date(#ty34) which it should not when #-symbol not lies in between two characters like in above string as mentioned. After # it should accept only number and character DT like - #12, #DT, (#12), ( #12 ), ( #dT ), #DT, p_date( #DT, ), p_calc( #12 ) etc.

Comment: Can you help me out from this pattern so that it will accepts all the cases.

Comment: I tried to modify your regex pattern show that will accepts rest cases too. But I'm not getting what I need to change so that it will accepts rest cases too.
So , can you modify pattern so that it will accepts the remaining cases too ?

Comment: the pattern you provide is correct but when #-symbol not lie in between two alphanumeric character then in that case after #only the number and character DT is valid not alphanumeric  like wew212#wew121 , 12we#121ew are valid but #12we , #we12 , rate(#we12) are not valid because after # it contains both number and character

Comment: Yes it's working fine for #we21, #32we , d(#we12) but when I passed string like p(#21we)  excepted which should not.

Comment: it's accepting #323 but not accepting P_price(#34) which is valid previously accepting this case also.

Comment: can you modify it so that it accept above valid pattern too.

Comment: Can you help me out from this pattern so that it will accepts all the cases.